# Lightswitch Deployment Issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am trying to deploy a lightswitch app via web deployment. This will be a web application. It seems to publish just fine, and after a long period of troubleshooting, a coworker and I were able to finally get an admin user added, but now the site just shows a white screen with "Loading," but nothing else ever happens. We are using .NET 4.0. There is no indication of an error, and we have the trace logs available, but I don't see anything that looks like an error. Does anyone know what might be happening. I am using VS 2012.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a LightSwitch HTML5 project? Or LightSwitch Silverlight Desktop?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this until just now. It is a Silverlight Desktop.

Comment: Have you set a default screen in the desktop client's screen navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you're Debugging the app locally, and you're using forms authentication, and have the "Application Administrator Already Exists" option selected in Publish settings, you're always taken to the Desktop Client in order to "Setup" administrators. Simply navigate to the HTMLCLient (or whatever you've called it) by typing "http://myapp.com/HTMLClient" into the address bar. This should allow you to use your app, or at least login.